# Stack Overflow reputation API

Tags: php, wordpress, stackexchange-api

I am creating a WordPress widget plugin that displays different types of social media fans and follower counts.  After that I feel that I could also include Stack Overflow reputation for specific users.

How can I get the Stack Overflow reputation for any user?  Is there any API for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this link  : http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage/methods/users

Ex:
http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/users/[users id]

For me:
http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/users/716492

Comment: this api is shutdown after May 12th 2014.

Comment: there is a new API ( replace USER_ID )
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/[USER_ID]?&site=stackoverflow